# Cancel subscribe of request Angular

Tags: angular, http

I'm sending any requests on angular to back-end part. I send the same request with different parameters when entering new values ​​into the input, due to the server’s response, the data is updated to the front end part. How I can implement cancellation of waiting for an old request if a new one has already been sent? In order not to render components for each request, but only for the last?

Some code of this:

```
    getNotes() {
    this.isLoaded = false;
    this.noteService.getNotes(this.page, this.sortBy, this.searchNoteValue)
        .subscribe((notes: Note[]) => {
            this.userNotes = notes;
            this.isLoaded = true;
        }});
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling the backend more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be define a property notesSubscription: Subscription

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
...
notesSubscription: Subscription;
```

and modify your getNotes method

```
getNotes() {
this.isLoaded = false;
if (this.notesSubscription) {
    this.notesSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
this.notesSubscription = this.noteService.getNotes(this.page, this.sortBy, this.searchNoteValue)
    .subscribe((notes: Note[]) => {
        this.userNotes = notes;
        this.isLoaded = true;
    }});
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `switchMap` operator of RxJS. You can subscribe to the `notes$` observable and trigger the request as much as you want.

Disclaimer: code was not tested, merely to instruct a way of programming

```js
private _getNotesTrigger = new Subject<{page:string,sortBy:string, searchNoteValue:string}>();

public notes$ : Observable<Note[]> = this._getNotesTrigger
       .pipe(switchMap(theParams => this.noteService.getNotes(theParams));

getNotes() {
    this.isLoaded = false;
    this._getNotesTrigger.next(this.page, this.sortBy, this.searchNoteValue)
}
```